# Entity Framework database first does not generated all complex types for stored procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've just recreated my edmx file because of some problems with the table mapping and I seem to be having some problems when I add my stored procedure. The edmx creates only 23 complex types instead of 25 as it should.

I've tried deleting the procedure reading them but it didn't work. All the guides I find online show me how to create the mapping when you already have a complex type generated.

Can anyone tell me how to manually generate the complex type or how to create it?

Comment: Are you able to manually import the function by - right clicking in the designer surface -> Model Browser. In Model Browser on the function that was not imported - right lick -> Import. In the dialog select complex type. Also can you show how a stored procedure that was not imported looks like in the edmx (the storage model section)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for Complex type i always use simple =

```
List<Complex_Type_Class> _lsComplexReturn =EntityObject.ExecuteStoreQuery<Complex_Type_Class>(@"storeProcedureName;");
```

and class is like

```
public class Complex_Type_Class
{
 //all returns value's get set 
 }
```